# Move scanned values(from barcode scanner) to a specific cell in excel using VBA

Tags: vba

I have a excel spreadsheet at work ( see image bellow) that I need to fill up with dates that are embedded into bar-codes. 
[Example of the file that I'm using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENwzz.jpg) 
The idea is to have an attendance list (of the personnel trained in a specific date) and with the help of the bar-code scanner to insert automatically the date in line with each dame that have been present to the training session using VBA.

I manage to create a necessary bar-code to be read by the scanner, I add into the training attendance list the date, name of the training and dames of each attendee into bar-code format but I cant create the VBA program to insert the date of the training performed into a specific cell that I want.

Comment: What are you getting stuck on? Any errors? What's the code you're trying? [edit] your question to provide a bit more detail so it's easier to help.

Comment: Why don't you just select the correct cell to activate its editing mode and just scan your bar code? A barcode scanner is more or less basically just an automated keyboard so your computer should be able to read its input correctly as if you were typing it with a keyboard.